# My password length is not verified

Tags: php, database, pdo

I'm creating a registration page for a website. When i submit the form even with less lengths than those specified i go straight to the index page.The data is also not saved in my database. Anyone know why this is occurring? The following code is from the script called register.php

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            //on récupère les données entrées
            $name = $_POST['userName'];
            $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
            $birthDate = $_POST['day'].':'.$_POST['month'].':'.$_POST['year'];
            $languageM = $_POST['langueM']; //langue maternelle
            $languageE = $_POST['langueE']; //langue étudiée
            $email =  $_POST['mailInput'].'@'.$_POST['schools'];
            $Password1 = $_POST['Password1'];
            $Password2 = $_POST['Password2'];

                if($name&&$firstName&&$birthdate&&$languageM&&$languageE&&$email&&$Password1&&$Password2)
                {
                    //hashage du mot de passe
                    $password1_md5 = md5($Password1);
                    $password2_md5 = md5($Password2);

                    if ($Password1==$Password2)
                    {
                        // taille du nom ou du prénom
                        if (strlen($userName)>25||strlen($firstName)>25)
                        {
                        echo "Nom  ou prénom trop long !";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //check password length 
                            if (strlen ($password1)>25 || strlen ($password1)<6)
                            {
                                echo "Le mot de passe doit etre entre 6 et 25 caractères";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                 //connection à la bdd
                                try
                                {
                                    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
                                }
                               catch(Exception $e)
                               {
                                 die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
                               } 
                                 //enregistremnt de l'étudiant dans la bdd
                                $bdd->exec('INSERT INTO nouveau_membre(nom,prenom,date_de_naissance,langue_maternelle,langue_etudiee,email,passe)
                                            VALUES($name , $firstName , $birthDate, $languageM , $languageE , $email,                                                                               $password1_md5)');
                            }


                        }

                    }
                    else echo "Les mots de passe ne sont pas identiques";

                }           

        }
        header('Location: Index.php');
    ?>
```

and here's my form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Accueil</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/">

</head>

<body>
    <?php include("header.html"); ?>

    <div id="formulaireInscription">
        <h3 id="titreIncrivez">Inscrivez-vous!</h3>
        <form action="Register.php" method="post" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
              <div id="renseignementgenerale" class="form-group">
                <label for="userName"><br />Nom:
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" placeholder="Entrez votre nom" required="required"></label><br />

                <label for="firstName">Prénom:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="Entrez votre prénom" required="required">

                <div class="form-group" id="birthdate">
                    <label>Date de naissance:</label>
                        <label for="dayInput">Jour</label>
                        <select name="day">
                          <option value="1">1</option>
                          <option value="2">2</option>
                          <option value="3">3</option>
                          <option value="4">4</option>
                          <option value="5">5</option>
                          <option value="6">6</option>
                          <option value="7">7</option>
                          <option value="8">8</option>
                          <option value="9">9</option>
                          <option value="10">10</option>
                          <option value="11">11</option>
                          <option value="12">12</option>
                          <option value="13">13</option>
                          <option value="14">14</option>
                          <option value="15">15</option>
                          <option value="16">16</option>
                          <option value="17">17</option>
                          <option value="18">18</option>
                          <option value="19">19</option>
                          <option value="20">20</option>
                          <option value="21">21</option>
                          <option value="22">22</option>
                          <option value="23">23</option>
                          <option value="24">24</option>
                          <option value="25">25</option>
                          <option value="26">26</option>
                          <option value="27">27</option>
                          <option value="28">28</option>
                          <option value="29">29</option>
                          <option value="30">30</option>
                          <option value="31">31</option>
                    </select>

                  <label for"monthInput">Mois</label>
                    <select name="month">
                        <option value="month1">Janvier</option>
                        <option value="month2">Février</option>
                        <option value="month3">Mars</option>
                        <option value="month4">Avril</option>
                        <option value="month5">Mai</option>
                        <option value="month6">Juin</option>
                        <option value="month7">juillet</option>
                        <option value="month8">Aout</option>
                        <option value="month9">Septembre</option>
                        <option value="month10">Octobre</option>
                        <option value="month11">Novembre</option>
                        <option value="month12">Décembre</option>
                    </select>
                  <label for"yearInput">Année</label>
                  <select name="year">
                       <option value="year1">2014</option>
                       <option value="year2">2013</option>
                       <option value="year3">2012</option>
                       <option value="year4">2011</option>
                       <option value="year5">2010</option>
                       <option value="year6">2009</option>
                       <option value="year7">2008</option>
                       <option value="year8">2007</option>
                       <option value="year9">2006</option>
                       <option value="year10">2005</option>
                       <option value="year11">2004</option>
                       <option value="year12">2003</option>
                       <option value="year13">2002</option>
                       <option value="year14">2001</option>
                       <option value="year15">2000</option>
                       <option value="year16">1999</option>
                       <option value="year17">1998</option>
                       <option value="year18">1997</option>
                       <option value="year19">1996</option>
                       <option value="year20">1995</option>
                       <option value="year21">1994</option>
                       <option value="year22">1993</option>
                       <option value="year23">1992</option>
                       <option value="year24">1991</option>
                       <option value="year25">1990</option>

                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="langueM">

                    <label>Langue maternelle:</label>

                    <select  name="langueM"> 
                        <option value="langue1">Français</option> 
                        <option value="langue2">Anglais</option> 
                        <option value="langue3">Espagnol</option> 
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" id="langueE">

                    <label>Langue étudiée:</label>

                    <select  class="langueE"> 
                        <option value="langue1">Français</option> 
                        <option value="langue2">Anglais</option> 
                        <option value="langue3">Espagnol</option> 
                    </select>

                </div>

              </div>

            <label >Adresse email:</label>

            <div>
                <div class="mailliste">
                    <input name="mailInput" type="text" placeholder="Entrez votre  email" required="required">@
                    <select name="schools" onchange="VerifListe();"> 
                       <option value="valeur1">rms.fr</option> 
                       <option value="valeur2">icade.es</option> 
                       <option value="valeur3">esb.de</option> 
                    </select> 
                </div><br>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inscriptionInputPassword1">Mot de passe:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Password1" placeholder="Entrez votre mode passe" required="required"><br>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Password2" placeholder="Répétez votre mode passe" required="required">
          </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Inscription"/>


        </form>    
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your `header` call will always run, because it is outside the `if` block. Do you get any errors when you run it? Also, your script is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and your password length checking is rather pointless, since you're doing the length check AFTER you do htmlspecialchars. e.g. a password that's simply `""""` would pass, because `&quot;&quot;&quot;&quot;` is 24 encoded chars, even though the password is only 4 ACTUAL characters.

Comment: I get no error, i just go straight to my index page.

Comment: i modified the code according to his advice and still my if isn"t working. @meda

Comment: @SanassiCissé see my answer below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MD5 not safe anymore so change it when you get a chance

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//on récupère les données entrées
$name = $_POST['userName'];
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$birthDate = $_POST['day'].':'.$_POST['month'].':'.$_POST['year'];
$languageM = $_POST['langueM']; //langue maternelle
$languageE = $_POST['langueE']; //langue étudiée
$email =  $_POST['mailInput'].'@'.$_POST['schools'];
$Password1 = $_POST['Password1'];
$Password2 = $_POST['Password2'];

//C'est mieux de verifier avec isset()
if(isset($name,$firstName,$birthdate,$languageM,$languageE,$email,$Password1,$Password2))
{

    if ($Password1===$Password2)//triple equals more secure
    {
         //hashage du mot de passe
         $password1_md5 = md5($Password1);
         $password2_md5 = md5($Password2);
        // taille du nom ou du prénom
        if (strlen($userName)>25||strlen($firstName)>25)
        {
            echo "Nom  ou prénom trop long !";
            exit();//plus la peine de continuer
        }
        else
        {
            //check password length 
            if (strlen ($password1)>25 || strlen ($password1)<6)
            {
                echo "Le mot de passe doit etre entre 6 et 25 caractères";
                exit();//plus la peine de continuer
            }
            else
            {
                 //connection à la bdd
                try
                {
                    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
                    //ajoute cette line pour connaitre l'erreur
                    $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    //enregistremnt de l'étudiant dans la bdd
                    $stmt =  $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO nouveau_membre(nom,prenom,date_de_naissance,langue_maternelle,langue_etudiee,email,passe)
                                            VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
                    $success = $stmt->execute(array($name , $firstName , $birthDate, $languageM , $languageE , $email,$password1_md5));

                    if($success){
                        header('Location: Index.php');
                    }else{
                        echo "INSERT a echouer!!";
                        exit();//plus la peine de continuer
                    }
                }
               catch(Exception $e)
               {
                 die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
               } 
            }

        }

    }
    else{
        echo "Les mots de passe ne sont pas identiques";
        exit();//plus la peine de continuer
        }

}else{
 echo 'une des variables nest pas set';
}          

}
```

Comment: please dont downvote and stay quiet, at least be fair and tell me where the mistake is

Comment: the error is on line 9. Undefined index:langueE . But i defined it the same way as langueM i don't know what i'm missing here @meda.

Comment: @SanassiCissé your missing the name attribute `<select  class="langueE" name="langueE">`

Comment: sorry for this one i fixed it and didn't save :s .It is working. Really thank you man and all of those who answered.

Comment: @SanassiCissé welcome bro, if you ever need my help again hit me up

Comment: my alert messages are displayed between the 2 passowrds input.is it possible to change their position? I'm using bootstrap.i want them to be at the top of the page before the name input

Answer (score 1):

Typos:

```
    if (isset($_Post['submit']))
                ^^^^---here
```

PHP variables are case sensitive, which means `$_Post` is an undefined variable. Since `$_Post` is never defined, your ENTIRE form handling code block is bypassed.

Try

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

instead. And turn on `display_errors` and `error_reporting` in your php.ini. If you had those on, you'd have been warned about using an undefined variable.

Comment: display_errors and error_reporting are on cause i got undefined variable issues before but it didn't report for this.